# No entry for terminal type "unknown" Error

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I am periodically seeing the following text show up in my apache2 error logs:

```
No entry for terminal type "unknown";
using dumb terminal settings.
```

There is no reference to what is causing this error to be thrown.  I would appreciate help figuring out 1) How can I track down the source of this error and 2) what might an appropriate solution be?

Answer (score 1):

What is the setting of your TERM Variable?
You can set them normally at `/usr/share/terminfo/` as I understood that should be by default `vt100`.

Answer (score 1):

The error means:

- you have a library or apache module that is using ncurses or similar library that can render text in a terminal
- the TERM environment variable is set to "unknown"

You can check the environment of a process with `ps e $PID` or with `cat /proc/$PID/environ |sed 's/[\x0]/\n/g'` where PID is the process id.

To find which library is using `curses`, `ncurses`, `slang`, check the binaries with `ldd`.